# List & Label web report designer cross browser compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report, reporting, listlabel

I'm planning to use list & label as a reporting tool for my MVC Web Application, I downloaded the trial version and the sample code was really helpful.

I'm almost settled on using this as my app's reporting tool but I'm thinking twice on their web app report designer tool, because I needed to install the chrome extension before I can use it.

I'm using version LL v.20

So my questions are:

1. Is the chrome extension really needed for the designer to work? I'm thinking that if my app goes live, will I require my clients to install this plugin first?
2. Will the designer have issues on other browser? So far I haven't seen extensions/plugins for IE (only Fireforx, Safari, Opera, Chrome).

PS. If all else fail, can you suggest an alternative for this? The reporting tool that I need is web-based and allows end-users to edit the reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, you need to install the plugin on the client side.

2) For IE, there's a Designer ActiveX. Simply open your existing app in IE, you should be offered to install the OCX right away.

As to your general concerns:

We plan to replace the plugins with a client-side application that can be one-time installed with a couple of clicks in LL21. The reasoning is the step-by-step deprecation of plugins by most browser vendors. Changing between the plugins and the new designer app will be quite easy. The new designer will also support previewing at design time. Depending on when you plan to ship your application it may well be worth the wait till October.

Comment: I guess my app can wait. Thanks for this great update! Anyway, just to confirm, you are going to "replace plugins with client-side application" is the designer app a separate web application? or can I still integrate this to my web app?

PS. Will this designer app be compatible across browsers?

Comment: It will be a Windows application that talks to your web app via WebAPI. This communications channel will be handled automatically for you. It will feel and work just like the plugins. If you want, we can add you to our beta program which will give you access in september already.

Comment: Ah, got it. That would be great, how can I be added to your beta program?

Comment: Just drop us a line via info at combit dot net and refer to this thread.

Comment: Just to keep this question updated - the Designer has been released as planned. List & Label also has the web based Ad-hoc Designer starting with version 23, which is platform independent.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried List and Label Web Designer and found that installing additional application for all users is not a good idea. Will look for another solutions, may be FastReport.Net. That online designer is realy online and can work not only on Windows.